# Understanding Inheritance in a Class function (python)

Tags: python, class

I'm having trouble understanding why when a local variable in a class function is updated, the same variable in the calling function also changes.

In this simple example, when `class_func` is called, it will take from the parent `func` the variable my_var, and in each instance my_var will be back to `[]`.

But after the first time `c.class_func` is called, `my_var` in the function `func` is changed. And I don't understand why that would be?

Appreciate any insight.

```
class my_class :
    def class_func(self, my_var):
        if my_var == [] :
            my_var += [1]

def func (classes, my_var) :
    for c in classes :
        print(my_var)
        c.class_func(my_var)
        print(my_var)


class1 = my_class()
class2 = my_class()

func(classes=[class1, class2], my_var=[])
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance. You're using the same value of `my_var`, not making a copy of the list.

Comment: Isn't the `my_var` in `class_func` local to the function?

Comment: my_var that you give in func is passed as a reference to all the function calls. Meaning you always manipulate the original my_var object when modifying the referenced object from the class_func.

Comment: understood, so what would be the smarter way to do this?

Comment: It's not even clear why you're using classes here. `my_var` is just a local variable, not a class attribute. It would all be the same with ordinary functions.

Comment: This isn't my actual function, I just created a simple example to illustrate the problem I was having. My understanding was that a variable defined within a function would not affect variables in another function by the same name.